# Headers for Linux - VS Unix Extension

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio extension ([LinuxDevelopmentExtension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e)) to write programs for unix-based OS. For working with sockets, I'm using headers, such as:

```
<sys/socket.h>
<netinet/in.h>
<arpa/inet.h>
```

Problem: programs building without errors, but in the IDE these headers is marks as unreachable, that brings some inconvenience. How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually copy those header files to your IDE PC, and add them to the include path in the project build settings.

It works so that any local (i.e. Windows) paths for headers are used by the IDE for IntelliSense, etc. - while remote (i.e. Linux) paths are used by the compiler.